# How do I print out an"AttributeError" error with my Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I use a command to check which channel my bot is in. If it is in a channel, everything is output nicely. But if the bot is not in a channel I get the console entry: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`. My code looks like this:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def channel(self, ctx):
    bot_channel = ctx.guild.voice_client.channel
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        title=f":eyes:  Ich befinde mich hier: {bot_channel}",
        color=self.bot.get_embed_color(ctx.guild)))
    if bot_channel is None:
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("❌")
```

This is about the lower part with `if bot_channel is None`. Nothing happens here and only the output is shown in the console. What would be the correct method here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NoneType` doesn't have **any** attributes

```py
>>> foo = None
>>> print(foo.value)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute 'value'
```

I'm telling you this, cause `ctx.guild.voice_client` can be `None` if the bot isn't connected to any voice channel, there are two ways you can get away with that.

1. Using `try/except`

```py
try:
    bot_channel = ctx.guild.voice_client.channel
except AttributeError:
    return await ctx.send('Bot is not in a voice channel')
```

2. Checking first if `voice_client` is `None`:

```py
voice_state = ctx.guild.voice_client
if voice_state is None:
    return await ctx.send('Bot is not in a voice channel')

bot_channel = voice_state.channel
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the first method works fine!